# h:commandButton is not invoking bean method

Tags: jsf

I am trying to  do some work when the `h:commandButton` is clicked. I am using `jsf 2.2` as I am sending multipart data. I have 3 *commandButtons* in my form, The first 2 are working fine whereas the 3rd *commandButton* is not working.

This is my jsf page code:

```
 <h:form id="userSetup" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                    <div style=" margin-left: 250px; padding-top: 10px;width: 150px;margin-top: 100px;">
                        <img id="profile-picture" src="http://www.aspirehire.co.uk/aspirehire-co-uk/_img/profile.svg" height="120"  width="120"></img>
                        <button  onclick="addProfilePicture();return false;" class="cff-button"  style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: -10px;white-space: normal;width: 150px;">Add Profile Picture</button>
                    </div>


                    <br/><br/>
                    <h:inputFile   id="profilePicture"  value="#{uploader.profilePicture}" a:hidden="true" onchange="displayImage(this)">
                        <f:validator validatorId="imageValidator"></f:validator>
                    </h:inputFile>

                 <div class="user-input-div">
                    <h:messages id="response-message" style="color: red"></h:messages>

                    <h:inputText id="skills" a:placeholder="Skills" class="cff-inputText " ></h:inputText>
                <br/><br/>
                <button class="cff-button " style=" white-space: normal"  onclick="toggleCertificateInput('#{certificateInput.clientId}',true);return false">Add Certificate</button>
                <br/><br/>

                <h:panelGroup id="certificate-input"  layout="block" binding="#{certificateInput}" a:hidden="true" >
                    <h:inputText id="certificateName" value="#{uploader.certificateName}" class="cff-inputText" a:required="true" a:placeholder="Certificate Name" binding="#{certificateName}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="stringValidator"></f:validator>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:inputText id="certificateLink" value="#{uploader.certificateLink}" class="cff-inputText" a:placeholder="Link" binding="#{certificateLink}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="urlValidator"></f:validator>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save Certificate" class="cff-button" action="#{uploader.saveCertificate()}" >
                        <f:ajax  execute="certificateName certificateLink response-message"  onevent="function hide(data){ if(data.status === 'success'){ toggleCertificateInput('#{certificateInput.clientId}',false) }  }"  render="userSetup:certificate-output certificateName certificateLink response-message"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <button class="cff-button" onclick="toggleCertificateInput('#{certificateInput.clientId}',false);return false">Cancel</button>
                </h:panelGroup>


                <h:panelGroup id="certificate-output-div" binding="#{certificateOutput}">
                 <h:dataTable  var="certificate" id="certificate-output" value="#{uploader.certificates}">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText id="certificate-output-name" value="#{certificate.certificateName}    " class="certificate-name"></h:outputText>
                        <h:outputLink  id="certificate-output-link"  class="cff-link" value="         #{certificate.link}">view certificate</h:outputLink>
                        <span id="remove" onclick="removeCertificate('#{removeCertificate.clientId}');" class="remove">           &times;</span>
                        <h:commandButton  a:hidden="true" binding="#{removeCertificate}" id="removeCertificate" action="#{uploader.removeCertificate(certificate)}" value="Remove" class="cff-button" >
                            <f:ajax execute=" certificate-output  certificate-output-link certificate-output-name " render="userSetup:certificate-output response-message"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>


                //This command button is not working
                <h:commandButton  class="cff-button" action="#{uploader.saveAndContinue()}" value="Save and Continue">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
                    </div>  



            </h:form>
```

This is my model code:

```
    @ManagedBean(name="uploader")
@ViewScoped
public class userDataUploader {

   private String about_Yourself;
   private String skills;
   private List<Certificates> certificates;
   private Part profilePicture;
   private String certificateName;
   private String certificateLink;
   @ManagedProperty(value="#{userData}")
   private User userData;


   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){

       certificates =  new ArrayList<Certificates>();
   }

    public List<Certificates> getCertificates() {
        return certificates;
    }

    public void setCertificates(List<Certificates> certificates) {
        this.certificates = certificates;
    }



    public Part getProfilePicture() {
        return profilePicture;
    }

    public void setProfilePicture(Part profilePicture) {
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }

    public String getAbout_Yourself() {
        return about_Yourself;
    }

    public void setAbout_Yourself(String about_Yourself) {
        this.about_Yourself = about_Yourself;
    }

    public String getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public User getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }

    public void setUserData(User userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public String getCertificateName() {
        return certificateName;
    }

    public void setCertificateName(String certificateName) {
        this.certificateName = certificateName;
    }

    public String getCertificateLink() {
        return certificateLink;
    }

    public void setCertificateLink(String certificateLink) {
        this.certificateLink = certificateLink;
    }

    public void addCertificate(){
        out.println("about to add new Certificate");

    }

    public void removeCertificate(Certificates certificate){
        out.println("about to remove certificate  " + certificate.getCertificateName() + "  "  + certificate.getLink() );
        certificates.remove(certificate);
        out.println(certificates.isEmpty());
    }



    public void saveCertificate(){


        Certificates certificate = new Certificates();
        certificate.setCertificateName(certificateName);
        out.println(certificateName + "\n" + certificateLink);
        certificate.setLink(certificateLink);
        certificates.add(certificate);
        out.println("new certificate has been added");
        certificateName = null;
        certificateLink = null;

        out.println(certificates.isEmpty());
    }

    public String saveAndContinue(){

        out.println("welcome to save and continue function");
        out.println(skills);
        boolean result = true;
        Uploader uploader = new Uploader(userData,certificates,getSkillsArray(),profilePicture);
        String returnString = "success";

        out.println("about to save all data");


        try {
           uploader.saveAllData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           out.println(ex);
           result = false;
        }

        if(!result){
            returnString = "false";
        }

       out.println("return string is "  + returnString);

        return returnString;
    }

   private String[] getSkillsArray(){
       return skills.split(" ");
   }




}
```

Can somebody please tell me where I am going wrong? ThankYou.

Comment: make sure that you have a <h:head> instead of <head> ?

Comment: Your answer is with 99% certainty in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value

Comment: No,, it's 100%, but answer?? it's comment for confirmation to find the possible solution before give the duplicate link.

Comment: @YeWin I did take a look at the answer but I am kind of new to jsf can you please tell me  how to fix this please I have been stuck for hours

Comment: could you please change p:commandButton and test me for it's work or not?

Comment: is there any errors warnings in a concole?
a view ideas: try actionListener instead of action
try to remove ajax call and see if uploader.saveAndContinue() is executed

Comment: @alex no there no errors and i have tried removing ajax

Comment: @YeWin I really dont want to use primefaces. I want to do this with plain jsf

Comment: @YeWin: I have no clue what you mean by 'but answer??' And yes, I did not blindly voted to close as a duplicate. MrJOIS, try to follow what is written in the duplicate. If you have problems doing so with e.g. the first step, please state what your problem is. Learning to 'debug' is the best and important thing to learn doing anything. It is like learing to fish instead of asking for fish.

Comment: your first comment is aim to Op, this was my mistake :)

Comment: i wonder if bean scope is effecting this. Try to change viewScoped to sessionScoped etc